# Layout for Android. Fluid layout and a fixed layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I've to develop an Android application that needs to show data using a similar layout.
I need two parts of screen:

- A layout with a fluid height that vary on resolution of device
- Second layout that show content in a fixed size

How to do this? I've used relativelayout and linearlayout but I haven't found a solution.
Could you help me?

[image: Image representing my layout wireframe]

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html. Both the layouts you mentioned will do this task.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/fixedlayout"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/fluidlayout" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/fixedlayout" >
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

More efficient solution using `LinearLayout`

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

For a `LinearLayout` set top layout to `android:layout_weight="1"` (and height to `0dp`) and bottom `layout_height` to either a fixed value or `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#00FF00" />

</LinearLayout>
```